# How to judge the mathematical model in image processing

Tags: mathematical-modeling, image-processing

To remove the noise from the image, we base on some mathematical model(minimizing the energy functional).

**Q**: For different models A and B(different functionals), How can we say which one is better in math. language?

e.g. in R.O.F. model people minimize the functional $\int_\Omega\sqrt {u^2_x+u^2_y}$ in $L^1$ norm, why it is better than model to minimize the $\int_\Omega(u_{xx}+u_{yy})^2$ in $L^2$, with the same constraint conditions?

Is this because that $L^2\subset L^1$?

Answer (score 1):

For justifying the objective function, you need a model for the data, for example a probabilistic model. In that case, you can say that the maximum likelihood estimator (i.e. minimize the objective function $-L( \theta| x)$ the likelihood function) is optimal for estimating the parameters of this model.

Now the main idea in signal processing is that choosing a model for the data is equivalent to choosing an objective function for estimating the parameters. And in most cases :

- even for the simpler models, the maximum likelihood estimator is very 
  complicated (and hard to minimize)
- even for the simpler objective functions, the underlying model is very complicated

So really there is no solution, you can't choose in the same time a good model and a good objective function, and so you have to choose the objective function without any rigorous justification, other than "it works in those specific cases".